# Hibernate: how to find out the one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between Two or more table from DatabaseMetadata or at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have generated a mapping xml(Clazz.hbm.xml) file for the dynamically created POJO class. But unable to define the tags like SET,Composite-id,Component or any relationship between tables/relations beacause I am unable to find out them from the java code using DataBaseMetaData. Please help me Find out.

For `<class></class>`  tag I have this code to find or Generate Class name:

```
DatabaseMetaData metadata = sessionImp.connection().getMetaData();
ResultSet tables = metadata.getTables(null, "SDP", null,new String[] { "TABLE" });

while (tables.next()) {
            tName = tables.getString(3);
}
```

for properties i.e. `<property/>` tag I have this code to identify columns

```
ResultSet columns = metadata.getColumns("SDP", "SDP", tName, null);
while (columns.next()) {
    sop(columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
}
```

It will be great if I find something like this for relationships and `<composite-id>` tags.

**UPDATE **

I have tried these:

```
ResultSet ketSet = metadata.getExportedKeys(null, "SDP", tableName);

        while (ketSet.next()) {
            PojoGenerator.pkey = ketSet.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
            System.out.println("Meta data exported key data ["+ketSet.getString(4)+"]");
        }

        ResultSet primaryKeys=metadata.getImportedKeys("SDP", "SDP", tableName);

        while(primaryKeys.next()){
            PojoGenerator.pkey = primaryKeys.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
            System.out.println("Meta data primary key data ["+primaryKeys+"] key : ["+primaryKeys.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME")+"]");
        }

        ResultSet resultSet1= metadata.getPrimaryKeys("SDP", "SDP", tableName);

        while(resultSet1.next()){
            PojoGenerator.pkey = resultSet1.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
            System.out.println("get primary keys ["+resultSet1.getString(4)+"]");
        }
```

but every function responses are unsatisfactory.

I have a table which consists of this:

```
 <composite-id name="id" class="com.telemune.autoGeneratedPojo.CrbtAlbumOpLogHistoryId">
        <key-property name="msisdn" type="string">
            <column name="MSISDN" length="15" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="subscriberType" type="string">
            <column name="SUBSCRIBER_TYPE" length="1" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="eventTime" type="date">
            <column name="EVENT_TIME" length="7" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="interfaceType" type="string">
            <column name="INTERFACE_TYPE" length="1" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="rbtCode" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="RBT_CODE" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="albumId" type="string">
            <column name="ALBUM_ID" length="10" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="opCode" type="boolean">
            <column name="OP_CODE" precision="1" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="eventCharged" type="string">
            <column name="EVENT_CHARGED" length="1" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="updatedBy" type="string">
            <column name="UPDATED_BY" length="15" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="callId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="CALL_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

Another table consists:

```
<set name="crbtWalletMasters" table="CRBT_WALLET_MASTER" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="MSISDN" length="15" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.telemune.autoGeneratedPojo.CrbtWalletMaster" />
    </set>
```

Another Table consists:

```
<composite-id name="id" class="com.telemune.autoGeneratedPojo.CrbtWalletContentId">
        <key-property name="walletId" type="int">
            <column name="WALLET_ID" precision="9" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="rbtCode" type="long">
            <column name="RBT_CODE" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="crbtRbt" class="com.telemune.autoGeneratedPojo.CrbtRbt" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="RBT_CODE" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="crbtWalletMaster" class="com.telemune.autoGeneratedPojo.CrbtWalletMaster" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="WALLET_ID" precision="9" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

1.How can I identify this composite key or set/relationships from both the directions?

another table consists:

```
<key-property name="rbtCode" type="string">
            <column name="RBT_CODE" length="200" />
        </key-property>
```

2. how do I deifferentiate between property/key/column key-property from metadata?

Comment: Have you investigated the `getImportedKeys`, `getExportedKeys`, and `getCrossReference` methods of [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)?

Comment: yes let me edit the question. I have tried these:

Comment: @GordThompson, All these method gives **PKTABLE_CAT, PKTABLE_SCHEM, PKTABLE_NAME, PKCOLUMN_NAME, FKTABLE_CAT, FKTABLE_SCHEM, FKTABLE_NAME, FKCOLUMN_NAME, KEY_SEQ, UPDATE_RULE, FK_NAME, PK_NAME**  type of things not the specific relation. How could a primary key, or foreign key may help to find the relationship type(what-to-what)?